# Partial refresh in XPages causing other controls to not execute event handlers?

Tags: xpages

I have an xpage with a bunch of controls on it.  One of them is a simple label that I'm updating with a partial refresh every five seconds.  (I'm implementing a document locking scheme, and the label indicates whether someone has locked the document.)  A button on the page fails to execute its event handler if I press it while the partial refresh of the label is occurring.  At other times, it works fine.  Is this a known issue, or is there perhaps something else going on that may explain this behavior?

(I'm unable to post sample code, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your approach. Instead of a partial refresh, have an independent Ajax call to an [XAgent](http://notessensei.com/blog/2008/12/xagents-web-agents-xpages-style.html) for your locking (IMHO 5 sec is way to frequent, the WebDAV standard uses 30sec).
The [openNTF WebDAV](https://github.com/OpenNTF/WebDAVForDomino) project has locking code you might be able to repurpose for your needs. 
The independent Ajax call frees up the jsf lifecycle to run your other events.

Comment: Thanks.  So this behavior I'm seeing is expected?  If a partial refresh is happening on the page, no event handlers will be processed?  I never realized that.  It seems like hit-or-miss processing of user actions would be a bad thing in general and a reason to avoid partial refreshes under some circumstances. Thank you for the other pointers!